# We want to launch an HR app in around 3 months. What are the main things we should do and when?

Tags: startup, launch

1. We want to launch an HR app in around 3 months. What are the main things we should do and when?
2. What should we do to increase our landing page traffic and have a large target audience base before the launch?
3. Any good outline/schedule templates you can link to?
4. Top things to focus on?